# CSOM C# Caml Query on managed metadata field not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, caml

I am trying to find an item in a list where the managed metadata field is equal to a certain text value. This is the code that I have which is not getting any items in the list (ListItemCollection count = 0). Is this the right way to go about the query?

Update: I added loading the list item collection. Now I am getting all of the items in the list

```
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Name of List");
string textValue = "Meta Data Term Text";
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = @"<Where>
    <Contains>
        <FieldRef Name='MetaDataFieldInternalName' />
        <Value Type='Text'>" + textValue + @"</Value>
    </Contains>
</Where>";
ListItemCollection lColl = list.GetItems(query);

clientContext.Load(lColl);  //added
clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); //added

ListItem lItem = lColl[0];
clientContext.Load(lItem, item => item["InternalName1"], item => item["InternalName2"]);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: You need to wrap your query in ‘<View>‘ tags  in CSOM

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the following query? I am thinking based on field type it can be format as below.

```
<Where>
    <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='officelocations' />
        <Value Type='TaxonomyFieldTypeMulti'>seattle</Value>
    </Eq>
</Where>
```

This is for a multi-value field. The type should be `TaxonomyFieldType` for single value type field.

Answer (score 0):

From @Robert's comment, here is the answer for your query that are missing some tags:

```
CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
query.ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'>
                    <Query>
                        <Where>
                            <Contains>
                                <FieldRef Name='MetaDataFieldInternalName' />
                                <Value Type='Text'>" + textValue + "</Value>
                            </Contains>
                        </Where>
                    </Query>
                </View>";
```